# How do I do with HQL, many to many?

Tags: hibernate

[image]

Here is my database structure. Relation many to many. I want to make a selection of authors who have written the same book. With SQL, I did. How do I do with HQL?

```
   Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM authors, books, author_book as ab WHERE ab.authorID=authors.authorID AND ab.bookID = books.bookID AND ab.bookID = :id");
   query.setInteger("id", 1);
   List list = query.list();
   Iterator<Object[]> iter = list.iterator();
   while (iter.hasNext()) {
       Object[] obj = iter.next();
       System.out.println(obj[0] + " " + obj[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming the entity names are Book and Author and that Book has authors attribute:

```
select a.firstName, a.lastName from Book b join b.authors a where b.id = :id
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the entities Authors, Books and AuthorBook.

Can you try the following query.

```
String hql = "select a.firstName, a.lastName from Authors a, Books b, AuthorBook ab where ab.authorId=a.authorId and ab.bookId=b.bookId and ab.bookId=:id";

List<Object[]> resultList = session.createQuery(hql).setInteger("id", 1).list();

for(Object[] result : resultList)
{

        System.out.println("First Name : " + result[0]);
        System.out.println("Last Name : " + result[1]);
}
```