# Having difficulty joining a ManyToMany Table in Spring to get hql to work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have two tables, book and author that are a many to many relationship

book.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="BookAuthor", 
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"),
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="author_id"))  
private List<Author> authors;
```

Author.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
private List<Book> books;
```

I am now trying to join both tables in a query

```
String hql = "select book from Book book" +
    " join book.authors author where author.id = :author_id";
```

However I am getting these errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:  
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
```

Am I naming the join ids wrong in my book.java or do I have a wrong naming in my query?

Comment: just asking, what tutorials did you follow to learn hibernate? I need some help right now :)

Comment: I kind of suspect there are some invisible characters in your HQL causing the problem....

Comment: What is the unexpected token that you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do with HQL, many to many?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855930/how-do-i-do-with-hql-many-to-many)