# How to retrieve data from many to many relationship in HQL, with Spring and JPA,when the joinTable is not an entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller, hql

I have a similar case as this question [a link] ([How do I do with HQL, many to many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855930/how-do-i-do-with-hql-many-to-many))
I want to have the number of users (entity 1) for each libelle of role (entity 2). I defined a relation many to many between User and Role.

I am using Spring MVC, Hibernate, MySQL and JPA.

Entity 1: User

```java
@Entity(name = "user")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String email;
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Role> role;
```

Entity 2: Role

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;
    private String libelle;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_role") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user") }
    )
    private List<User> user;
```

JPA repository

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
 @Query(value = "select new map( count(u.id) as numberOfUsers,r.libelle as roleLibelle )  FROM user  u join  role r where r.ID =: ????  group by r.libelle")
    List<Object> countByRoleList();
```

I am trying to figure out what =:id proposed in the question that i mentioned, have to be in my case. Instead of the "????" i tried ID, id , ID_role. All what i get is the error

> "Named parameter not bound : ".

How can i solve that?

Comment: Why would the query have a parameter? Read the JPQL chapter of the hibernate user guide. It has a whole section about joins.

Comment: But without the where clause, i get the error " Validation failed for query for method public abstract"

Comment: Of course, because your query is not valid JPQL. Which is why I advised you to read the documentation about JPQL: so that you can learn the syntax of the language.

Comment: can you give me a link please

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the type of your parameter is long. it's name is abc and it refer to an id. 
Follow these steps:

- Remove the space in front of your param .
  so you will have (=:abc) not (=: abc).
- Your query depends on an external parameter, uses the @param annotation for the specified param.
  so you will have 
  ".....countByRoleList(@Param("abc") long id );"

A code exemple

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
@Query(value = "select new map( count(u.id) as numberOfUsers,r.libelle as roleLibelle )  FROM user  u join  role r where r.ID =:abc  group by r.libelle")
List<Object> countByRoleList(@Param("abc") long id);
```

Note: abc is a provided param . It can come from an HTML page, a function. you can also provide it manually ...

Comment: Please @CodIn 